# Can I do multiple imputation for a categorical data using mice() in r?

Tags: r, categorical-data, multiple-imputation, mice

Okay, so please bear in mind I am very new to R and statistics in general! My professor has drilled into us that multiple imputation is the best way to deal with missing data (haven't been shown how to do it so trying to teach myself), but I am now doing a project that involves missing categorical data.

The dataset is very mixed in terms of class, but one of the categorical variables contains about 20% missing data. The variable is 'Health status' and is based on a survey question that asked 'how would you describe your health status?' with 'good', 'average', and 'poor' as the options (I know these are vague but they can't be changed).

Basically, I'm wondering how I might go about dealing with this missing categorical data, and whether I can still use mice() to impute? I can't find a definitive answer anywhere, at least not in terms that I can understand.

Any help would be much appreciated!

Comment: Categorical data does not inhibit the use of multiple imputation.  This specific categorical variable appears to be ordered so you could impute this data using any 'method' in the 'mice' function that works for "ordered" data.  These include: pmm, midastouch, sample, cart, rf, and polyr.